# ! Arithmetic overflow error with \documentclass{amsart}

Tags: align, numbering, amsart, flalign

I need to write a mathematical program with numbered equations and a name of the mathematical model. I tried the following code (find it here [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83918/labeled-linear-program-with-labeled-equations-and-wide-objective-function): )

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\newlength{\LPlhbox}
\begin{document}
    
    
    \settowidth{\LPlhbox}{(P.1)}%
    \noindent%
    \parbox{\LPlhbox}{\begin{align}
            \tag{P.1}\label{My first LP Block}
    \end{align}}%
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2cm}
        \begin{flalign}\notag
            & \makebox[0pt][l]{$\displaystyle{}\max \sum\limits_{v \in V} x_v + \sum\limits_{e \in E} y_e + 10000\gamma$} \\
            \label{this line can be referenced}
            & \text{s.t.} & x_v + x_w   & \geq  0                 && \forall \{v,w\} \in E && \\
            &             & y_3         & \geq 0                  && \forall e\in E        && \\
            &             & (\delta(U)) & \geq \frac{1}{2}(|U|-1) && \forall U \subseteq V
        \end{flalign}~
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error`! Arithmetic overflow.`. If I use the `\documentclass{article}` the code works, do you have any solution?

Comment: What is this code suppose to do in the first place?

Comment: Don't use `align` for this, `equation` seems to work just fine (at least it compiles)

Comment: with `equation` I get the following error `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.`. I need to write a mathematical model where each row is an equation that must be numbrered and I need to have a label to the mathematical model, in the given code, the label is (P.1)

Comment: I said replace `align` not `flalign` there are no `&` in the parbox `align`

Comment: @daleif this is working without error, thank you. But now I have the equations's numbers from the left, I need these numbers to be on the right

Comment: @daleif And yet the underlying issue is interesting: apparently, `amsart` does not like an `align` environment with only a `\tag{..}` but otherwise empty. No issue with standard classes.

Comment: @campa amsart does some things differently.

Comment: @user247149 no you don't it is just `equation` that seems to have a super large size. No idea what is going on here. Needless to say I would never do something like this.

Comment: @daleif can you give us another code that gives the same form of mathematical model?

Comment: It's *always* a bad idea to use a multi-line `amsmath` display environment for a one-line display.  (Granted, this isn't documented as well as it could be, but really, it's in the same category as marking a coffee cup "Warning, contents may be hot.")